# Cells in tableview are compressed and shrunk

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

2 days ago I started developing an APP as a school project with Swift and Storyboard.
Now I've started to use UITableViews and also have Cells design, but somehow they are generated and reduced in size and I don't understand exactly why.

How i designed it:
[image: Storyboard]
How it looks:
[image: Ipad 7th gen]

I wrote these costum subclass for the Cell:

```swift
import UIKit

class ContentView: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CellPriority: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var FromCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CellImage: UIImageView!
}
```

and this is my ViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var ContentTable: UITableView!
    var ContentArray = [ContentView]()
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        
   
        
        
        ContentTable.dataSource = self
        ContentTable.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }
    
    
    
    var titleArray = ["asd", "bsd", "csd", "dsd", "esd", "fsd", "gsd", "hsd", "isd", "jsd", "ksd", "lsd", "msd", "nsd", "osd", "psd", "qsd", "rsd", "ssd", "tsd", "usd", "vsd", "wsd", "xsd", "ysd", "zsd"]
    var descArray = ["asd", "bsd", "csd", "dsd", "esd", "fsd", "gsd", "hsd", "isd", "jsd", "ksd", "lsd", "msd", "nsd", "osd", "psd", "qsd", "rsd", "ssd", "tsd", "usd", "vsd", "wsd", "xsd", "ysd", "zsd"]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ContentTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContentView
      
        let image = UIImage(named:"")
        cell.CellImage.image = image
        
        
        cell.CellTitle.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.CellDesc.text = descArray[indexPath.row]
        
      
        cell.CellTime.text = "resultE"
        cell.CellPriority.text = "!!!"
        cell.FromCell.text = "lol"

        return cell
    }
}
```

(I have everything else which is unnecessary, regarding the problem, has been deleted)
(These were things like the "erstellen" button and so on.)

Thank you very much

Comment: You may have forgot to set the size of cell in tableView properties (not in cell)

Comment: I do not find this property

Comment: The property is rowHeight.

Comment: oh i found it thank you very much

Comment: but how do i make a separation between items?

Comment: In [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) search for « Customizing the separator appearance»

Comment: @PixelCoin - you shouldn't need to set `.rowHeight` if you have your constraints in your cell setup correctly. Show us a screen-shot of the document outline, with all constraints expanded.

Comment: Either use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method to define the height of your cells (to prevent compression) for giving proper top to bottom constraints to the element of your cell then use.automaticDimension to determine constraints automatically.